# (Novice) Java generics: Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I have a class called `Generic`. I am assigned to create a boolean method called `matches()` that receives another `Generic` as a parameter and returns true if the two stored values can be found in the current `Generic`. Order of the values is not important.

```
public class Generic<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    ...
    public boolean matches(Class Generic){
    return this.valueA = that.valueA && this.valueB = that.valueB): } 
    ... 
}
```

I am scrabbling to figure out how the class is able to store multiple values for `valueA` and `valueB` and distinguish `this.valueA` from the other one. Should I refer to the concept called reflection for more info?

Comment: If you don't want to use comparable, don't use it :) you have anyways written your own function named matches() which takes another object of same type. And comparing values should be straight forward. If object has a and b as parameters, write getters for them and call those functions to compare the values.

Comment: Why does your `matches` method take an `Object` as a parameter instead of a `Generic`, if you expect the parameter to be a `Generic` (since you're doing an `instanceof` check)?

Comment: Thank you, @SunilChakravarthy. I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of comparable as I'm a beginner. How is the class able to store multiple values each for `storeValueA` and `storeValueB`?

Comment: @Jesper, it was because I am still not sure how I can have multiple instances of `Generics` so I created class `AnotherGeneric` thinking I would need to pass it as an object.

Comment: Let's be clear here.  Are you looking to support a generic parameter into your method, or are you looking at a class called `Generic`?  Remember, in Java's conventions, classes, interfaces, and enums are all capitalized.

Comment: Is `valueA` and `valueB` of type `T`? Otherwise, what is purpose of `T`? --- Also, your code should use `==`, not `=`, for comparison of primitive values, if that is what `valueA` and `valueB` are. Or `compareTo()` if they are type `T`.

Comment: @Makoto - definitely trying to pass a class called `Generic`, which is of type `T`.

Comment: So, to be perfectly clear:  `Generic<T>` as opposed to `<T extends Generic> T`, right?

Comment: @Andreas, yes, `valueA` and `valueB` are type T, but I am required to name the comparing method `matches()`. Is there a way to name `compareTo()` as `matches()`?

Comment: @wbxyqeuv See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37532720/5221149). Your class `Generic` is not *itself* a `Comparable`, it just requires that `T` implements/extends `Comparable`, so you can use the `compareTo()` method inside `matches()` when comparing `valueA` and `valueB`.

Comment: @Makoto, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* the purpose of type parameter `T` is for fields `valueA` and `valueB` to be of that type, and that `matches()` should use the fact that they are `Comparable` (since `T extends Comparable`), this is how:

```
public class Generic<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private T valueA;
    private T valueB;
    public boolean matches(Generic<T> that){
        return (this.valueA.compareTo(that.valueA) == 0 &&
                this.valueB.compareTo(that.valueB) == 0);
    }
}
```

Of course, assuming that the referenced type enforces that [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is *consistent with equals*, then you don't really need `Comparable` at all:

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T valueA;
    private T valueB;
    public boolean matches(Generic<T> that){
        return (this.valueA.equals(that.valueA) &&
                this.valueB.equals(that.valueB));
    }
}
```

Be aware that neither of these two examples can handle null values for `valueA` and `valueB`.

Comment: Thank you, @Andreas. This cleared a lot of confusion.